# Fetching JSON Data from Backend in Svelte not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, frontend, svelte

I am trying to fetch JSON data coming from the Backend. It is basically just some information about music videos. Nothing complicated.

I followed this tutorial here: https://morioh.com/p/e6b6f63fce3e
I tried coding exact the same what he did, with continents and stuff, well i copy and pasted. It did work. But mine doesn't.

The JSON output running on localhost:8081 is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Champion",
    "type": "Musical Video",
    "artist": "NAV",
    "featuredArtists": "Travis Scott"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Nice to Meet Ya",
    "type": "Musical Video",
    "artist": "Wes Nelson",
    "featuredArtists": "Yxng Bane"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "No Stylist",
    "type": "Musical Video",
    "artist": "French Montana",
    "featuredArtists": "Drake"
  }
]
```

This data was generated through a Spring Boot Application. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.testphase1.video;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping/*(path="api/v1/video")*/
public class VideoController {


    @GetMapping
    public List<Video> video() {
        return List.of(
                new Video(1,
                "Champion",
                "Musical Video",
                "NAV",
                "Travis Scott"),
                new Video(2,
                    "Nice to Meet Ya",
                    "Musical Video",
                    "Wes Nelson",
                    "Yxng Bane"),
                new Video(3,
                        "No Stylist",
                        "Musical Video",
                        "French Montana",
                        "Drake")
        );
    }
}
```

Then I have got the 3 following svelte files, which are not able to fetch the data.

App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import Video from "./Video.svelte";
    import Videos from "./Videos.svelte";
    let videos;
    let video;
  </script>
  
  <h1>Available videos to play</h1>
  <main>
      <Videos {videos} />
  </main>
```

Video.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let video;
</script>

<article>
    <h1>{video.title}</h1>
    <small>
        Type: <b>{video.type}</b>
    </small><br/>
    <small>
        Artist: <b>{video.artist}</b>
    </small><br/>
    <small>
        Featured Artist: <b>{video.featuredArtists}</b>
    </small>
</article>

<style>
    article {
      margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      margin: 0;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
```

Videos.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import Video from "./Video.svelte";
    let videos;

    onMount(async () => { 
        await fetch (`http://localhost:8081/`)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(data => {
            videos = data;
        });
    })
</script>

<main>
    {#if videos}
        {#each videos as video}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Video {video} />
                </li>
            </ul>
        {/each}
    {:else}
        <p class="loading">loading...</p>
    {/if}
</main>

<style>
    .loading {
      opacity: 0;
      animation: 0.4s 0.8s forwards fade-in;
    }
    @keyframes fade-in {
      from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
    }
    li {
      list-style-type: georgian;
    }
  </style>
```

**The output i expected:**

```
Available videos to play

title: Champion
type: Musical Video
artist: NAV
featuredArtists: Travis Scott

title: Nice to Meet Ya
type: Musical Video
artist: Wes Nelson,
featuredArtists: Yxng Bane

title: No Stylist
type: Musical Video
artist: French Montana
featuredArtists: Drake
```

**The output i got:**

```
Available videos to play
loading...
```

So basically it got caught in the else of "Videos.svelte"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't closing the express server when starting the dev session with Svelte? `localhost:8081` should return some json if you open it in the browser. I don't see any problem with the code itself you've shared that would cause this behaviour.

Something that could cause a bug down the line is the fact that you're passing an empty `videos` variable from `App.svelte` to `Videos.svelte`. `Videos.svelte` doesn't export the `videos` variable so you probably you're getting an error. To fix it, just change `<Videos {videos}/>` to `<Videos/>`.

Furthermore, you should consider using the [`{#await promise}` `{:then value}` syntax of svelte](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks). Something like the following:

```html
<script>
    async function getVideos() {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:8081')
        let data = await response.json()
        return data 
    }
</script>

<main>
    {#await getVideos()}
        <p class="loading">loading...</p>
    {:then videos} 
        {#each videos as video}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Have video {video}
                </li>
            </ul>
        {/each}
    {/await}
</main>
```

Comment: Still not working, Maybe i should have explained more how i created the json output. I added some info on original question.

Comment: So I added the part with Spring Boot Application, which was not covered in the tutorial, but the ouput has the same format. I don't get it. And yeah I had a spelling mistake in video.svelte feaUturedArtists --> featuredArtists.

Comment: Well I have little experience with the Spring framework and Java in general, so I'm afraid I'm not going to be able to help on that end. However, it works fine for me with an express server, so the problem seems to be the json generation. Sorry for asking again, but are you sure a browser shows that data when visiting `localhost:8081`?

Comment: Yeah 100%, i mean i can see it showing that. Even after refreshing and IntelliJ is not showing any sign of closed server on terminal.